# Find/print how many numbers are generated before finding the random number

Tags: java, random

How to find out and print how many numbers you generate before you find the random number?

I have tried many times, and I could not figure out how to print the numbers I generated before I got the prime number. Any guidance or help is greatly appreciated!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 int range = 1000000;
 Random generator = new Random();
 int p = generator.nextInt(range) + 2;

 while (!isPrime(p))
     p = generator.nextInt(range) + 2;
     System.out.println("A random prime number is " + p);
 }

 private static boolean isPrime(int N) {
 for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(N); i++) {
        if (N % i == 0)
             return false;
 }
 return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
while (!isPrime(p))
  p = generator.nextInt(range) + 2;
  System.out.println("A random prime number is " + p);
}
```

Will stop when p is actually prime. Otherwise, it'll generate a new random number, add two to it, and claim that the result is prime.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not figure out how to print the numbers I generated before I got the prime number* from this line I understand that you want the print generated numbers

You can do this way:

```
private static boolean isPrime(int N) {
System.out.println(N);
 for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(N); i++) {
        if (N % i == 0)
             return false;
 }
 return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding this code to the script:

```
   private static boolean isPrime(int N) {
      for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(N); i++) {
         if (N % i == 0)
            System.out.println(N+" can be divided by "+i);
            return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
```

You know what number it is can be divided by.

Answer (score 0):

Print statement you have in while prints the random number you generated during the process.In your code you will miss out the first generated number. In order to get all the number's you generated and prime number you can modify the code as below:

```
private static boolean isPrime(int N) {
          for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(N); i++) {
                  if (N % i == 0){
                     System.out.println("A random number is " + N);
                     return false;
                  }

           }
         System.out.println("Prime number is " + N);
         return true;
      }
public static void main(String[] args) {

      int range = 1000000;int count=1;
      Random generator = new Random();
      int p = generator.nextInt(range) + 2;

      while (!isPrime(p)){
          count++;
          p = generator.nextInt(range) + 2;
          //System.out.println("A random prime number is " + p);
      }

     System.out.println("Total count is"+count);
 }
}
```

I set a count variable in order to verify. count should be equal to the number of times the random number was generated including prime number.